# GechoFx JSContext Namespace

Tags: c#, windows, forms, namespaces, gecko

Does anyone know what the namespace is for JSContext. Ive tried the following with no success

using Gecko;

using Gecko.DOM;

using Gecko.JQuery;

using Gecko.Services;

using Gecko.Net;

using Gecko.Interop;

using Gecko.Events;

using Gecko.IO;

using Gecko.Services;

using Gecko.DOM.Events;

using Gecko.DOM.Svg;

using Gecko.DOM.Xml;

using Gecko.DOM.Xul;

using Gecko.Collections;

```
using (AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(geckoWebBrowser1.Window.JSContext))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-29.0/issue/21/autojscontextevaluatescript-not-returning
I also encountered the same problem you
Here is the solution.